# IndexError - 'List Index out of Range'

Tags: python, list, python-3.4, indexoutofrangeexception, index-error

Here is the specific error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\New_folder\minsweeper_game_study.py", line 259, in game
    screen.blit(numbers[j.val], (j.x + 10, j.y + 10))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In the code the part before that is:

```
for i in lst:
       for j in i:
           if j.visible == True:
               screen.blit(white, (j.x, j.y))
               screen.blit(numbers[j.val], (j.x + 10, j.y + 10))
           if j.flag == True:
               screen.blit(flag, (j.x + 10, j.y +10))
           if j.flag == False and j.visible == False:
               screen.blit(grey, (j.x, j.y))
```

What I'm attempting to do is have the user click on a square in the generated graph, and once they click, it then checks to see what the number is. This tells it what the number can possibly be range wise.

Here is the link to the whole code:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2RXBYwkd-QBfllUUXMtalRNZmZRemhLV1cyNlVKS3JTQlNyMWFjbGlXUWxnUDk4RmM4REU&usp=sharing

The particular file is the `minsweeper_game_study.py`, the other files there are needed to execute that file.

Comment: And where is the code? Please add the relevant part of the code to your question. If you just provide a link to some files, nobody will understand the issue.

Comment: It doesn't say "out of order", it says "out of range". That means you're trying to access (or change) an element past the end of the list. For example, `x = [1,2,3]`, then `print(x[10])`, you'll get the same error.

Comment: Sorry just added the code, how would i fix that error, still new to python so not quite sure what i'm fully doing

Comment: Second, can you explain what's supposed to be in `numbers` (in particular, how many things), whether you're sure that's really what's in `numbers`, what's supposed to be in `j.val`, and whether you're sure that's really what's in `j.val`? Because without that, nobody can help you without trudging through all of your code trying to figure out what you intended and guess all the possible places you might have gone wrong.

Comment: You fix that error by… not doing that. It doesn't make sense to ask for element #10 when there are only 3. Whether the fix is to have 8 more elements, or to ask for #2, or to not ask for an element at all, depends entirely on what you were trying to do.

Comment: Well its supposed to be a minesweeper game, with 1-9 possibility of choices for a tile, 9 is a bomb, 1-8 near the bomb and how many bombs around

Comment: Basically this only pops up every once in a while, if the user has failed to win, somehow it generates a number outside my numbers, right?

Comment: Also, your link to the code is broken; it goes to a list of files, none of which look like Python source. And even if it worked, don't put vital information only in an external document—some people can't follow the link, or won't trust you enough to do so; if it goes stale because you edit the file or change your Google Drive account, the question becomes useless; and it can't be indexed by the search engine, meaning people with similar programs won't see your problem. Please read the Help on how to ask questions.

Comment: Its the minsweeper_game_study one

Comment: "Off by one" errors are very easy to make, and tend to be the kind of thing that only show up in edge cases—maybe if the users goes all the way to the bottom right corner, you try to look at a space past the end of the grid. You might want to try running in the debugger to see what all the values are at the time it raises. Or, if you don't know how to use pdb, put a `try`/`except` that prints out everything that might possibly be relevant.

Comment: When I click that file, it just says "No preview available" and goes back to the list of files. Apparently Google Drive doesn't know that Python source counts as text? At any rate, you need to put the relevant code in the question here. (And before you say "But I have too much code", the relevant code is not all of your code, it's a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with all the extraneous stuff removed. Again, read the help.)

Comment: I have seen the debugger, but it tells me i can only use when not busy, and i only see that window when the program is running

Comment: Note that if you are creating a program in which the number of elements in a list may vary (based on randomness, user interaction, etc), you can use a `try` / `except` block, using `except IndexError:` and then typing your 'backup plan' for the list-index-out of-range scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the index you are trying to reach is outside the range of the allocated memory. Specifically, this is in the snippet that says 'numbers[j.val]'